# Difference between Spring R2DBC using EntityCallbacks vs Mapping and use case?

Tags: postgresql, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am trying to understand the difference between R2DBC EntityCallbacks and R2DBC Mapping. I am trying to use it in a Multitennat application, where I would like to map the TennantId using a web filter and request context holder to set it before making the DB call.

In the above context which will be the better approach so that handling the tenant id is separated from the business logic for the current endpoint?